# How to capture docker-compose run logs in a cron job?

Tags: docker-compose

I run docker-compose from a cronjob as follows:

```
05 16 * * * cd /home/apps; docker-compose run service1 sh ./update_all_all.sh /data >>/var/log/works.log
```

I'd like to capture the outputs from the run into works.log, it runs, but no works.log file, any idea how to make this works?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem of capturing the compose logs with the following shell script:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs -t -f --no-color > compose.log &
# Maybe do something more before cleaning up...
docker-compose stop
```